# How IncreaseAllowance and DecreaseAllowance function solve mitgation problem?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, erc-20-approve

I was going through openzeppline code for ERC20 Token and found that While working with approve function in IERC20 interface they describe mitigation problem : [Link](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-approve-address-uint256-)

I don't understand how increaseallowance and decreaseAllowance solve the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the links you'll end up to the description of the vulnerability: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YLPtQxZu1UAvO9cZ1O2RPXBbT0mooh4DYKjA_jp-RLM/edit . Basically an attacker (the one who has been given allowance in advance) can theoretically insert his own `transferFrom` transaction before the allowance is reduced, thus gaining almost-double allowance.

So let's assume user A has an allowance of 10 from user B to user B's tokens. User B wants to reduce this allowance to 8, for whatever reason, so B submits a `approve` transaction for 8. At that moment A can submit his own transaction, in which he spend some of the allowance (let's say he spends 5), and possibly gets the transaction processed before B's transaction. Once B's transaction goes through, A has used 5 of his original allowance, but still has an allowance of 8 remaining - which is not what B wanted.

If user B uses `decreaseAllowance` instead (so he'd submit a transaction to reduce the allowance by 2) user A would end up with 5 used allowance and only 3 allowance left after B's transaction. Which results in the exact functionality B wanted.

Comment: Note that this vulnerability is 100% hypotethical. incraseAllowance() was never needed and was later removed https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1758450219476234468

Answer (score 0):

In mitigation problem , If suppose Alice allows Bob to transfer N ERC20 tokens , initially and then changes want to change it to M. Then Bob can transfer N+ M Tokens , but using increaseAllowance or DecreaseAllowance we just add the amount i.e difference between N and M i.e P , therefore P = N-M and N+P is the amount ALice want Bob to spend